# JavaScript - Proxy set vs. defineProperty

Tags: javascript, object, es6-proxy, object-properties

I want to build a proxy that detects changes to an object:

- New properties are defined.
- Existing properties are changed.

**Code Sample 1 - defineProperty**

```
const me = {
  name: "Matt"
}

const proxy = new Proxy(me, {
  defineProperty: function(target, key, descriptor) {
    console.log(`Property ${key} defined.`);
    return Object.defineProperty(target, key, descriptor);
  }
});

proxy // { name: 'Matt' }

proxy.name = "Mark";
// Property name defined.
// Mark

proxy.age = 20;
// Property age defined.
// 20
```

**Code Sample 1 - Observations**

- `proxy` has a property `name` which is what I'd expect.
- Changing the `name` property tells me that `name` has been defined; **not** what I'd expect.
- Defining the `age` property tells me that `age` has been defined; as I'd expect.

**Code Sample 2 - set**

```
const me = {
  name: "Matt"
}

const proxy = new Proxy(me, {
  defineProperty: function(target, key, descriptor) {
    console.log(`Property ${key} defined.`);
    return Object.defineProperty(target, key, descriptor);
  },
  set: function(target, key, value) {
    console.log(`Property ${key} changed.`);
    return target[key] = value;
  }
});

proxy // { name: 'Matt' }

proxy.name = "Mark";
// Property name changed.
// Mark

proxy.age = 20;
// Property age changed.
// 20
```

**Code Sample 2 - Observations**

- `proxy` has a property `name` which is what I'd expect.
- Changing the `name` property tells me that `name` has been changed; as I'd expect.
- Defining the `age` property tells me that `age` has been changed; **not** what I'd expect.

**Questions**

- Why does `defineProperty` catch property changes?
- Why does the addition of `set` override `defineProperty`?
- How do I get the proxy to correctly trap `defineProperty` for new properties and `set` for property changes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Why does `defineProperty` catch property changes?

Because when you change a data property (as opposed to an accessor), through a series of specification steps it ends up being a [[DefineOwnProperty]] operation. That's just how updating a data property is defined: The [[[Set]] operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arguments-exotic-objects-set-p-v-receiver) calls [OrdinarySet](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryset) which calls [OrdinarySetWithOwnDescriptor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarysetwithowndescriptor) which calls [[DefineOwnProperty]], which triggers the trap.

> Why does the addition of set override defineProperty?

Because when you add a `set` trap, you're trapping the [[Set]] operation and doing it directly on the target, not through the proxy. So the `defineProperty` trap isn't fired.

> How do I get the proxy to correctly trap `defineProperty` for new properties and set for property changes?

The `defineProperty` trap will need to differentiate between when it's being called to update a property and when it's being called to create a property, which it can do by using `Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` or `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` on the target.

```js
const me = {
  name: "Matt"
};

const hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
const proxy = new Proxy(me, {
  defineProperty(target, key, descriptor) {
    if (hasOwn.call(target, key)) {
      console.log(`Property ${key} set to ${descriptor.value}`);
      return Reflect.defineProperty(target, key, descriptor);
    }
    console.log(`Property ${key} defined.`);
    return Reflect.defineProperty(target, key, descriptor);
  },
  set(target, key, value, receiver) {
    if (!hasOwn.call(target, key)) {
      // Creating a property, let `defineProperty` handle it by
      // passing on the receiver, so the trap is triggered
      return Reflect.set(target, key, value, receiver);
    }
    console.log(`Property ${key} changed to ${value}.`);
    return Reflect.set(target, key, value);
  }
});

proxy; // { name: 'Matt' }

proxy.name = "Mark";
// Shows: Property name changed to Mark.

proxy.age = 20;
// Shows: Property age defined.
```

That's a bit off-the-cuff, but it'll get you heading the right direction.

You *could* do it just with a `set` trap, but that wouldn't be fired by any operation that goes direct to [[DefineOwnProperty]] rather than going through [[Set], such as `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: (FWIW, I go into Proxy and traps and the surprising fact of the `defineProperty` trap getting triggered by setting data properties in Chapter 14 of my new book. Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: @Bergi - Gah, and I knew that, and I did it anyway. Not the first time, either. Thanks! Looking at it, I also had an unnecessary use of `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` (I was originally going to use the descriptor, then changed the code just to check for whether the prop existed. Fixed that, too.

Comment: This is an excellent question and answer. I'm surprised it hasn't gotten more views given how important Proxy can be for things like setting up bindings. I thought I knew everything about Proxy but never saw this detail. Turns out it was the details of defineProperty I had never fully understood. Years of going through the MDN docs once in a while hadn't clued me into this. Thanks for a real lesson this morning.